# Instagram: restrict keyword search to one user's photos?

Tags: search, instagram

How would I search my own Instagram photos for keywords in the title or comments? So basically, restrict a search to my own profile... or any single user for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but as far as the app or the website permit you can only search by username, place or hashtag